# declared as or declared

Tags: grammar, prepositions, american-english, british-english, conjunctions

The sentence is :-

> Supreme Court can declare the parliamentary laws as unconstitutional.

Do we have to use 'as' in the aforementioned sentence. What's the difference if we use it vs when we don't?

Comment: "Declared a holiday" is, I think, the usual way.

Comment: That's a different tense to your title.